# sh source can't find files

Tags: sh, dash-shell

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 installation. I seem unable to source files with `sh`, which is Ubuntu's default `dash`.

I have a file, lets say `build.env`, with some environment variables in it like this:

build.env:

```
SOMEVAR=something
A_VAR=some_value
```

I can source this on bash with `. build.env` or `source build.env`. If I try `. build.env` with sh, however, I get

```
sh: 1: .: build.env: not found.
```

I can `stat` or `cat` the file, but I can't source it. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `.` (dot) command is [required by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot), it should work in any implementation of `sh`. The error you got

> ```
> .: build.env: not found.
> ```

indeed comes from `.`. It's `build.env` that is not found.

It's because your `sh` follows the specification:

> If *file* does not contain a <slash>, the shell shall use the search path specified by `PATH` to find the directory containing *file*.

In your case `build.env` is nowhere in directories specified by your `PATH`. You need

```
. ./build.env
```

to source `build.env` that resides in the current working directory.

Notes:

- `.` (builtin) in Bash behaves as if `PATH` contained `.` (current working directory) at the end. This means `. build.env` would actually work in Bash. Probably this is the reason you expected it to work in `sh`.
- POSIX doesn't specify `source`.
- `cat build.env` (or `stat build.env` etc.) is different than `. build.env` because `cat` does not use `PATH` to locate `build.env`. For it `build.env` means `./build.env`.

Comment: I didn't expect that the different commands find files differently. Thank you, that is what I needed.